# An article before 'custom/default/`

Tags: grammar, adjectives, articles, definite-articles

I have a question about using articles.

I have always problems with understanding this topic.

The question is following :

Do we need to use an article before adjective, that have the similar meaning as an article.

For example

**Google is default start page in the Google Chrome browser.**
 or
 **Google is a/the default start page in the Google Chrome browser.**

So for me it sounds like default doesn't require an article. And there are other examples like `custom`...

Could you please explain this. And let me know if I've made any mistakes.

Comment: The usual form is: Google is _the_ default ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definite article 'the' is usually used in contexts when our reader or listener knows which particular thing or person etc. we are writing or talking about. It is also used before a noun which is unique or when there is no other one of its kind  as in your sentence, "Google is ***the default start page*** in the Google Chrome browser" - there is no other **default** start page except google.